# Error In Visual Studio 2012 architecture Code Generate With T4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, t4

I use  VS2012 for design UML Diagram and i use T4 for generate custom class and interface.

And i Use TFS for Source controler.

But since yesterday I'm getting an error and Codes are not generated.

```
5/13/2013 8:18:59 AM: Code generation or text transformation started.
5/13/2013 8:19:51 AM: Errors encountered in 'ClassTemplate.t4' while generating code     for     'Andish.CSS.Modeling.UMLDiagram::Model::Andish.CSS.Domain::BusinessDomain::Calculator::Grou    pPreCalculatingResult' -  (Class).
5/13/2013 8:19:58 AM: Code generation complete. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0.
5/13/2013 8:19:58 AM: Unable to write log file:      F:\Andish\AndishmandFramWork\Modeling\Andish.CSS.Modeling.UMLDiagram\CodeGeneration.Log.xml     - Access to the path     'F:\Andish\AndishmandFramWork\Modeling\Andish.CSS.Modeling.UMLDiagram\CodeGeneration.Log.xm    l' is denied.
```

this is a pic from my VS2012

[image]

and i get one error like down :

```
Error   44  Errors were generated when initializing the transformation object.     The transformation will not be run.  The following Exception was thrown:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at      Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating5DC31BF3C568533E6A5135685CF1D48CEE628C2D066E9F2E28996B    26FB846E02D5A1B9165E6B13EEEEA7BBA99E06465E913189341F3D59CE816F2CEB52FAEBA8.GeneratedTextTra    nsformation.AppliesToElement()
   at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.TextTransformation.ModelingTextTransformation.Init    ialize()
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PerformTransformation()
```

and i use t4 class like down

```
      <#@ Include File="TemplateHeader.t4" #>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  <#@ Modeling ElementType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Uml.Classes.IClass" Processor="ModelingProcessor" ApplyStereotypes="CSharp" #>
  <#@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Uml.AuxiliaryConstructs" #>
  <#@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Uml.Classes" #>
  <#@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.Extensibility.Uml" #>
  <#@ Include File="CSharpCommentHelpers.t4" #>
  <#@ Include File="CSharpHelpers.t4" #>
  <#@ Output Extension=".cs" #>
  <# 
      WriteAutoGeneratedWarningHeader();
    WriteLine("using System.Runtime.Serialization;");
    WriteLine("using System.ServiceModel;");
      string classNamespace = GetNamespace(this.Element.Namespace);
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(classNamespace))
      {
  #>
  namespace <#= classNamespace #>
  {
  <#
          PushIndent("\t");
      }
      WriteUsingStatements(this.Element);
      WriteLine("");

      System.Globalization.PersianCalendar PDate=new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
    DateTime BeforDate=new DateTime(PDate.GetYear(System.DateTime.Now),PDate.GetMonth(System.DateTime.Now),PDate.GetDayOfMonth(System.DateTime.Now),PDate.GetHour(System.DateTime.Now),PDate.GetMinute(System.DateTime.Now),PDate.GetSecond(System.DateTime.Now));
    string Date=String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}",BeforDate);
    WriteSinglelineDocComment("Author","Name = \"T4Generator\"","");
    WriteSinglelineDocComment("CreateDate","Date = \"" + Date+"\"","");
    WriteSinglelineDocComment("LastModifyUser","Name = \"T4Generator\"","");
    WriteSinglelineDocComment("LastModifyDate","Date = \"" + Date+"\"","");
    WriteSinglelineDocComment("Version","Number = \"1\"","");
    WriteSinglelineDocComment("Release","Number = \"1\"","");
      WriteSummaryComment(this.Element.Description);
      WriteTemplateTypeParameterComments(TemplateParameterNameDescriptionPairs(this.Element));
    //WriteLine("[ServiceErrorBehaviour(typeof(HttpErrorHandler))]");
      foreach(var comment in this.Element.GetModelStore().AllInstances<IComment>().Where(c => c.AnnotatedElements.Contains(this.Element)))
      {
          WriteRemarksComment(comment.Body);
      }
  #>
  <#
      WriteClassClrAttributes(this.Element);
  #>

  <#= ClassVisibility(this.Element) #><#= ClassUnsafeOption(this.Element) #><#= ClassStaticOption(this.Element) #><#= ClassAbstractOption(this.Element) #><#= ClassSealedOption(this.Element) #><#= ClassPartialOption(this.Element) #>class <#= ClassifierName(this.Element) #><#= ImplementedAndInheritedList(this.Element) #><# WriteClassifierConstraintOption(this.Element); #>
  {
  <#
      PushIndent("\t");

      // Write Attributes
      var ownedAttributes = this.Element.OwnedAttributes;
      foreach(IProperty attribute in ownedAttributes)
      {
          WriteSummaryComment(attribute.Description);
          WriteClassUmlPropertyDefinition(attribute);   
          WriteLine("");
      }
  #>
  <#
      // Write Associations
      var navigableOwnedEnds = GetNavigableOwnedEnds(this.Element, ownedAttributes);
      foreach(IProperty ownedEnd in navigableOwnedEnds) 
      {
          WriteSummaryComment(ownedEnd.OwningAssociation.Description);
          WriteSummaryComment(ownedEnd.Description);
          WriteClassUmlPropertyDefinition(ownedEnd);
          WriteLine("");
      }
  #>
  <#

      // Write Operations
      foreach(IOperation operation in this.Element.OwnedOperations)
      {
        WriteSinglelineDocComment("Author","Name = \"T4Generator\"","");
        WriteSinglelineDocComment("CreateDate","Date = \"" + Date+"\"","");
        WriteSinglelineDocComment("LastModifyUser","Name = \"T4Generator\"","");
        WriteSinglelineDocComment("LastModifyDate","Date = \"" + Date+"\"","");
        WriteSinglelineDocComment("Version","Number = \"1\"","");
        WriteSinglelineDocComment("Release ","Number = \"1\"","");
          WriteSummaryComment(operation.Description + GetCommentOfGlobalMethod(operation.Name));
          foreach (IParameter parameter in operation.OwnedParameters.Where(p => p.Direction != ParameterDirectionKind.Return))
          {
              WriteParameterComment(parameter.Name, parameter.Description);
          }
        WriteSinglelineDocComment("returns","","");

          if(GetStereotype(operation) == "method")
          {
              WriteMethodClrAttributes(operation);
              if(IsConstructor(operation) || IsDestructor(operation))
              {
  #>

  <#= MethodVisibility(operation)  #><#= operation.Name #>(<# WriteMethodParameterList(operation); #>)
  {
  }
  <#
              }
              else
              {
  #>
  <#= MethodVisibility(operation) #><#= MethodUnsafeOption(operation) #><#= OperationStaticOption(operation) #><#= ClassMethodOverloadOption(operation, this.Element) #><#= MethodPartialOption(operation) #><#= MethodType(operation) #> <#= operation.Name #>(<# WriteMethodParameterList(operation); #>)<# WriteClassMethodBody(operation); #>
  <#
              }

              WriteLine("");
          }
          else if(GetStereotype(operation) == "indexer") 
          {
              WriteIndexerClrAttributes(operation);
  #>

  <#= IndexerVisibility(operation) #><#= IndexerUnsafeOption(operation) #><#= OperationStaticOption(operation) #><#= ClassIndexerOverloadOption(operation, this.Element) #><#= IndexerType(operation) #> this[<# WriteIndexerParameterList(operation); #>]
  {
  <#
              PushIndent("\t");
  #>
  <#= IndexerGetVisibility(operation) #>get<# WriteClassIndexerAccessorBody(operation); #>
  <#= IndexerSetVisibility(operation) #>set<# WriteClassIndexerAccessorBody(operation); #>
  <#
              PopIndent();
  #>
  }
  <#
              WriteLine("");
          }
      }

      PopIndent();
  #>
  }
  <#
      ClearIndent();
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(classNamespace))
      {
  #>
  }
  <#  } #>

  <#+
      #region Inheritance

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the implemented and inherited types of the given class.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="aClass">The given class</param>
      /// <returns>implementedAndInherted types</returns>
      private static string ImplementedAndInheritedList(IClass aClass)
      {
          var list = ImplementedAndInheritedTypes(aClass);
          if(list.Any())
          {
              return " : " + string.Join(", ", list.Select(t => ElementType(t)));
          }
          else
          {
              return string.Empty;
          }
      }

      #endregion Inheritance

      #region Polymorphism

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the overload option of the indexer.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operation">The operation</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The class</param>
      /// <returns>The overload option for the operation</returns>
      private static string ClassIndexerOverloadOption(IOperation operation, IClass owner)
      {
          return ClassOperationOverloadOption(operation, owner);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the overload option of the method.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operation">The operation</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The class</param>
      /// <returns>The overload option for the operation</returns>
      private static string ClassMethodOverloadOption(IOperation operation, IClass owner)
      {
          if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(MethodPartialOption(operation)))
          {
              return ClassOperationOverloadOption(operation, owner);
          }
          else 
          {
              return string.Empty;
          }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the overload option of the operation.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operation">The operation</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The class</param>
      /// <returns>The overload option for the operation</returns>
      private static string ClassOperationOverloadOption(IOperation operation, IClass owner)
      {
          string overload = string.Empty;
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationAbstractOption(operation)))
          {
              overload += "abstract ";
          }
          else if(IsInheritedMember(operation, owner))
          {
              overload += "override ";
              if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationSealedOption(operation)))
              {
                  overload += "sealed ";
              }
          }
  //دلیل کامنت شدن حذف کلمه virctual از تعریف متد
  //        else if(IsOverridable(operation, owner))
  //            {
  //              overload += "virtual ";
  //             }
          return overload;
          }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the overload option of the property.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="property">The property</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The class</param>
      /// <returns>The overload option for the property</returns>
      private static string ClassPropertyOverloadOption(IProperty property, IClass owner)
      {
          string overload = string.Empty;
          if(IsInheritedMember(property, owner))
          {
              overload = "override ";
              if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertySealedOption(property)))
              {
                  overload += "sealed ";
              }
          }
          else if(IsOverridable(property, owner))
          {
              overload += "virtual ";
          }

          return overload;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the operation is overridable.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operation">The operation</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The class</param>
      /// <returns>true if the operation is an inherited member.</returns>
      private static bool IsOverridable(IOperation operation, IClass owner)
      {
          bool isPrivate = MethodVisibility(operation) == "private " || IndexerVisibility(operation) == "private ";
          return !isPrivate && string.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationStaticOption(operation)) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationSealedOption(operation)) && HasVirtualMembers(owner);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the property is overridable.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="property">The property</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The class</param>
      /// <returns>true if the property is an inherited member.</returns>
      private static bool IsOverridable(IProperty property, IClass owner)
      {
          bool isPrivate = FieldVisibility(property) == "private " || PropertyVisibility(property) == "private ";
          return !isPrivate && string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttributeStaticOption(property)) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertySealedOption(property)) && HasVirtualMembers(owner);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the classifier could have virtual memebers.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="aClass">The class</param>
      /// <returns>true if the property is an inherited member.</returns>
      private static bool HasVirtualMembers(IClass aClass)
      {
          return string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClassSealedOption(aClass)) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClassStaticOption(aClass));
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the property is an inherited member.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="property">The property</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The owner class of the property</param>
      /// <returns>true if the property is an inherited member.</returns>
      private static bool IsInheritedMember(IProperty property, IClass owner)
      {
          var types = ImplementedOrInheritedTypes(owner);
          foreach(IType type in types) 
          {
              IClassifier baseClassifier = type as IClassifier;
              if(baseClassifier != null) 
              {
                  ITemplateBinding templateBinding = GetTemplateBinding(baseClassifier);
                  IClassifier bindingClassifier = GetBindingClassifier(templateBinding);
                  if(bindingClassifier != null)
                  {
                      baseClassifier = bindingClassifier;
                  }

                  foreach(IProperty propertyInBase in GetOwnedProperties(baseClassifier))
                  {
                      bool isInheritedMember = IsInheritedMember(propertyInBase, property, templateBinding);
                      if(isInheritedMember)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          return false;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the property is an inherited member.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="propertyInBase">The property in base</param>
      /// <param name="propertyInSubClass">The property in subclass</param>
      /// <param name="templateBinding">The template binding</param>
      /// <returns>true if the property in the subclass is an inherited member; false if it is not or the base is an interface</returns>
      private static bool IsInheritedMember(IProperty propertyInBase, IProperty propertyInSubClass, ITemplateBinding templateBinding)
      {
          var propertyInBaseOwner = propertyInBase.Owner;
          if(propertyInBaseOwner is IAssociation)
          {
              propertyInBaseOwner = ((IAssociation)propertyInBaseOwner).SourceElement;
          }

          if(propertyInBaseOwner is IInterface)
          {
              return false;
          }
          else if(propertyInBaseOwner is IClass)
          {
              bool isInheritedProperty = IsInheritedProperty(propertyInSubClass, propertyInBase, templateBinding);
              bool isOverridable = IsOverridable(propertyInBase, (IClass)propertyInBaseOwner);
              return isInheritedProperty && isOverridable;
          }

          return false;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the operation is an inherited member.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operation">The operation</param>
      /// <param name="owner">The owning class of the operation</param>
      /// <returns>true if the operation is an inherited member.</returns>
      private static bool IsInheritedMember(IOperation operation, IClass owner)
      {
          var types = ImplementedOrInheritedTypes(owner);
          foreach(IType type in types) 
          {
              IClassifier baseClassifier = type as IClassifier;
              if(baseClassifier != null) 
              {
                  ITemplateBinding templateBinding = GetTemplateBinding(baseClassifier);
                  IClassifier bindingClassifier = GetBindingClassifier(templateBinding);
                  if(bindingClassifier != null)
                  {
                      baseClassifier = bindingClassifier;
                  }

                  foreach(IOperation operationInBase in GetOwnedOperations(baseClassifier))
                  {
                      bool isInheritedMember = IsInheritedMember(operationInBase, operation, templateBinding);
                      if(isInheritedMember)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          return false;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the operation is an inherited member.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operationInBase">The operation in base</param>
      /// <param name="operationInSubClass">The operation in the subclass</param>
      /// <param name="templateBinding">The template binding</param>
      /// <returns>true if the operation in the subclass is an inherited member; false if it is not or the base is an interface</returns>
      private static bool IsInheritedMember(IOperation operationInBase, IOperation operationInSubClass, ITemplateBinding templateBinding)
      {
          var operationInBaseOwner = operationInBase.Owner;
          if(operationInBaseOwner is IAssociation)
          {
              operationInBaseOwner = ((IAssociation)operationInBaseOwner).SourceElement;
          }

          if(operationInBaseOwner is IInterface)
          {
              return false;
          }
          else if(operationInBaseOwner is IClass)
          {
              bool isInheritedOperation = IsInheritedOperation(operationInSubClass, operationInBase, templateBinding);
              bool isOverridable = IsOverridable(operationInBase, (IClass)operationInBaseOwner);
              return isInheritedOperation && isOverridable;
          }

          return false;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the operation in subclass is inherited from the operation in base.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operationInSubClass">The operation in subClass</param>
      /// <param name="operationInBase">The operation in base</param>
      /// <param name="templateBinding">The template binding</param>
      /// <returns>if operation in subClass is inherited from the operation in base.</returns>
      private static bool IsInheritedOperation(IOperation operationInSubClass, IOperation operationInBase, ITemplateBinding templateBinding)
      {
          if(templateBinding == null)
          {
              return operationInSubClass.Signature == operationInBase.Signature;
          }

          if(operationInSubClass.Name != operationInBase.Name)
          {
              return false;
          }

          var subClassOperationOwnedParametersInOrder = GetOwnedParametersInOrder(operationInSubClass);
          var baseClassOperationOwnedParametersInOrder = GetOwnedParametersInOrder(operationInBase);
          int numOfSubClassOperationOwnedParameters = subClassOperationOwnedParametersInOrder.Count();
          if(numOfSubClassOperationOwnedParameters != baseClassOperationOwnedParametersInOrder.Count())
          {
              return false;
          }

          var parameterSubstitutions = templateBinding.ParameterSubstitutions;
           // find the newly defined template parameters
          var baseClassifier = (IClassifier)operationInBase.Owner;
          var subClassifier = (IClassifier)operationInSubClass.Owner;
          var subClassNewlyDefinedTemplateParameterNames = GetNewlyDefinedTemplateParameterNamesInSubClass(baseClassifier, subClassifier, parameterSubstitutions); 

          for(int i=0; i < numOfSubClassOperationOwnedParameters; i++)
          {
              var subClassOperationOwnedParameter = subClassOperationOwnedParametersInOrder.ElementAt(i);
              var baseClassOperationOwnedParameter = baseClassOperationOwnedParametersInOrder.ElementAt(i);
              if(subClassOperationOwnedParameter.Direction != baseClassOperationOwnedParameter.Direction)
              {
                  return false;
              }

              bool isParameterInBaseEnumerable = IsEnumerable(baseClassOperationOwnedParameter);
              bool isParameterInSubClassEnumerable = IsEnumerable(subClassOperationOwnedParameter);
              if(isParameterInBaseEnumerable != isParameterInSubClassEnumerable)
              {
                  return false;
              }

              if(!OneTypeOverridesTheOther(baseClassOperationOwnedParameter.Type, subClassOperationOwnedParameter.Type, parameterSubstitutions, subClassNewlyDefinedTemplateParameterNames))
              {
                  return false;
              }
         }

         return true;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the owned parameters in order: first is the parameter of return type, and then the rest of the parameters.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operation">The operation</param>
      /// <returns>List of owned parameters in order</returns>
      private static List<IParameter> GetOwnedParametersInOrder(IOperation operation)
      {   
          var orderedSet = Enumerable.Union<IParameter>(operation.OwnedParameters.Where(parameter => parameter.Direction == ParameterDirectionKind.Return), operation.OwnedParameters.Where(parameter => parameter.Direction != ParameterDirectionKind.Return));
          return orderedSet.ToList();
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Checks if the two type names are equal with considering of the template binding substitutions.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="propertyInSubClass">The property in subClass</param>
      /// <param name="propertyInBase">The property in base</param>
      /// <param name="templateBinding">The template binding</param>
      /// <returns>if property in subClass is inherited from the property in base.</returns>
.........
```

I can not copy all code of T4 template because max length in this post is 30000 carachter.

Comment: if i use another project it work

Answer (score 1):

The error message says access to 'F:\Andish\AndishmandFramWork\Modeling\Andish.CSS.Modeling.UMLDiagram\CodeGeneration.Log.xm    l' is denied.

Maybe the file is locked by TFS.
Try checking out the file before generating.